# get div element by jquery and backbone el

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view like that:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    $P.viewTypes.HeaderNavigation = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'header-navigation',
        id: 'headerNav',

        templateHeader: _.template(
            '<div id="headerNavLeft" class="js-header-left"></div>' +
            '<div id="headerNavRight" class="js-header-right"></div>'
        ),

        getDivElement: function() {
            var divEle = this.getDivEl('headerNav');
            alert(divEle.innerHTML);
            var backboneEl = this.el;
            alert(backboneEl.innerHTML);
        },

        getDivEl: function(id) {
            var divEle = $('<div>').attr('id', id);
            return divEle[0];
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.templateHeader());
            this.getDivElement();
            return this;
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

My question is, why in getDivElement, the divEle and backboneEl are different?
The divEle.innerHTML is empty string
The backboneEl.innerHTML is

In this case, how to do to get the divEle as backboneEl?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how both the Backbone element properties (`tagName`, ...) and `$('<div>')` work.

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> **el** `view.el`
>   [...]
>   `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties.

So `tagName`, `className`, and `id` are simply used by Backbone to create a node and hook it up as the view's `el`; nothing attaches the `el` to the page anywhere or makes it globally visible to anything, you have to do that yourself.

From the other [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> **jQuery(html, [ownerDocument])**
>   **Description:** Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

So `$('<div>').attr('id', id)` also creates a `<div>` (with the specified `id` attribute) but again this node isn't attached to anything on the page and is not visible. `$('<div>')` doesn't go looking for the node anywhere, it creates a new one.

When you instantiate your view, it creates a `<div id="headerNav" class="header-navigation">` as the view's `el`. Then when you call `getElDiv`, that function creates another `<div id="headerNav">` that isn't attached to anything or filled with anything. If you call `getElDiv` again, it creates yet another unattached node.

You don't need your `getDivEl` function at all, if you want to see the view's element, just look at the `el` property.